# Editing the questions in stack exchange

Tags: discussion

Why are some people in stackexchange more interested in editing questions posted by others rather than providing answers to questions. Are they just doing this for the rep?

Comment: Because people are lazy and take no time to format their code.. I'm going to indent their code properly before I spend anytime on it

Comment: Edits are approved by experienced SFSE folks, so just because some one changes it doesnt mean it will get approved. The peer reviewers review it and only if they think the edit is valid they approve it. If people just edit for points they will easily get caught with all the monitoring that happens through moderators and senior SFSE folks.

Comment: Also, you don't get points for edits after you've passed 2K rep.

Comment: There are times when you may not see questions that you can do a useful answer to, but you can still help on the site by editing questions and answers for clarity and helping to moderate. Answering questions is not the only activity necessary to keep this site useful.

Comment: If they can understand the question well and can edit it, why can't they provide the solution too? Are they lazy enough to give the solution?

Comment: @Aruna ? How is people editing questions affecting you? Surely it's for the good of the community no? I've seen many new users not know how to ask questions and not tag and format correctly. Most of the time I don't have the time to answer the question properly but editing it would help others answer it

Comment: if they can find out the mistake and can spare time in correcting the question why can't they help the user by providing solution to the problem?

Comment: @Aruna Just because you know how to ask a question well and try and help new users clarify what they are asking for doesn't mean that you know the answer to all the questions that can get asked here. The Salesforce ecosystem is growing quickly and with all the different clouds I doubt anyone has the knowledge to deal with all the questions asked.

Comment: +1 @DaveHumm. Salesforce is massive and I'd raise an eyebrow to anyone who said they knew **everything** about it; although some people seem that they're not far off. We're all learning here and don't know everything. Many of us are, however, native English speakers or fluent and can comfortably tidy up spelling and grammar and have used the site enough to understand how questions should be formatted.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

I think the best way is to ask the questioner to elaborate the problem clearly with screenshots[if necessary]. Editing or down voting the question neither help the community nor the questioner because only the questioner will have the proper understanding of what's wrong with his code or functionality. If there is serious spelling mistakes and irrelevant tags added to the question that leads to misunderstanding of the problem then its ok to edit the question. Down voting can be given only to wrong answers and not to questions. Down voting a wrong answer may help the other people to not waste time with that answer.

Comment: You really don't get it do you?

Comment: Down voting can be given to questions if a question is poorly researched. For example, "How do I query Contacts?!". The answer to that question is everywhere and assumes the poster did no research. Another example, "How do I unit test this class?" We're a community here to help with specific problems, unpaid, so you can do yours, paid. We're not a code-writing service. You can see a more in-depth discussion on downvoting [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/downvote-newcomers-poorly-posted-questions-and-answers), if interested.

Comment: On the subject of editing, it's not an attack on anyone. Although you've been told this; editing helps readability for someone who knows the answer even if the editor doesn't. Editing helps indexing so answers to already-asked questions can be found more easily even on Google so the same question doesn't get asked twice. It keeps the board tidy. Don't take offence to edits without answers. It serves a purpose. :)

Answer (score 12):

Because questions which are posted by new users are not formatted properly. There are grammatical mistakes. Sometimes these questions don't have proper tags associated with them. Many contributors have their favorite tags in which they're specialized. If questions don't have proper tags then it might not let them know that there has been question raised. Thus it reduces the chances of questions getting answered properly.

Formatting questions properly makes more readable and it's easier to understand. And hence it increases it's chances to get answered quickly.

Also for new users who likes to contribute can edit questions. If these edited questions are approved by senior members (more than 2000 reputation) of community then it earns them 2 reputation for each question edited. Once they reached beyond 2k then they don't get 2 reputation for editing a question.

Answer (score 9):

Rohit has really hit on the main reasons I would edit and not answer. There are a few tags in particular that are heavily abused by new users, especially anything with Salesforce in the tag name. For instance, many users will tag a post with `salesforce2salesforce` because they are trying to let us know their question is about the Salesforce platform, but their question has nothing to do with this feature. A large number of my edits are in an attempt to buck this trend and keep those tags dedicated to the features they represent.

---

Dave's comment really encapsulates what should be conveyed here as well:

> Just because you know how to ask a question well and try and help new users clarify what they are asking for doesn't mean that you know the answer to all the questions that can get asked here.

Many of us have spent enough time around here to know how to ask good questions that convey our problem clearly. Some of us are experienced enough with the platform to know how to answer a given question. The overlap between these two circles can be quite small on some questions.

---

Besides the reasoning for why someone would edit your post, you need to take a step back and realize that you are asking for people to **volunteer** their time to help you, probably with task you are being paid to perform. As such, your opinions expressed here in your question and comments are extremely entitled and do not show much appreciation for those efforts.

> If they can understand the question well and can edit it, why can't they provide the solution too? Are they lazy enough to give the solution?

This view is *reprehensible*, and if that is how you see the community, you're never going to get very much out of it or put very much into it. Learn to **appreciate the help others are trying to give**. Edits are an attempt to help you get what you need.

Comment: It's frusterating answering questions and they don't accept =s  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/182271/mixed-dml-operation-dml-operation-on-setup-object-is-not-permitted-after-you-ha/182272#182272

Comment: @EricSSH I believe this deserves a meta post on its own. What I do is wait for like a month and ask politely if my answer worked for them. If they don't reply and keep posting that means they are "takers". Not interested in enriching the community. I will never answer their questions because for me asking AND answering questions has been so vital in my Salesforce journey. A confirmed answered means I actually understand it. We are all learning

Comment: @Adrian Larson - I have posted a question few days back https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181589/overriding-standard-actions-of-objects-inside-napili-community . Is this question needs to be closed? Don't it have  enough stuff to be a question in salesforce stack exchange?