# Review Queues - Post quality

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see New Posts and/or "Reviewed Posts: with little to no action taken, or sometimes a simple downvote with no comment.

When reviewing Posts in Queues:

> - Dont be shy to skip if you are unfamiliar with the subject or are unsure as to what might be wrong.
> - Make sure you leave a comment to help the OP improve their post so others in the community can assist.
> - This has been mentioned in other posts here in Meta, please don't downvote without leaving an explanation or without upvoting someone else's
>     comment
> - If you downvoted posts for X,Y reason, make sure you review them and undo your downvote (or change to upvote) if the post has been modified appropriately.
> - If you haven't read [How Can We Encourage Civility](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/how-can-we-encourage-civility), take a few minutes to read it (I myself review it every once in a while =P)

If there are any other pointers other members might have when reviewing queues, feel free to share them. After all, we are here to help others, and ourselves become better at doing so.